# Ruby Parameter Passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I currently have the following snippets of code:

```
 <tbody>
  <% @requests.each do |request| %>
    <% @user = User.where(id: request[:student_id_id]).first %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @user.last_name.titleize %></td>
      <td><%= @user.first_name.titleize %></td>
      <td><%= @user.preferred_name.titleize %></td>
      <td><%= render :partial => 'documents/resumelink' %></td>
      <td><%= mail_to @user.email.downcase %></td>
      <% if request.allowed_companies.nil? || request.allowed_companies.empty? %>
        <td> <a class="no_selected_companies_button">No Restrictions</a></td>
      <% else %>
        <% @allowed_request = AllowedRequest.where(professor_id_id: @current_user[:id], student_id_id: @user[:id]).first %>
        <td><%= link_to("View Companies", allowed_request_path(@allowed_request) , class: "selected_companies_button") %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

in a partial view.  The documents/_resumelink partial looks like this:

```
<% if (@document != nil) && (@document.resume_file_name != nil) %>
  <%= link_to 'View Resume', @document.resume.url %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'No Resume available', '#'  %>
<% end %>
```

In the documents_controller I have it so it will before_action set_document (with no exceptions).  That definition looks like:

```
def set_document(user=@current_user)
  @document = Document.find_by owner_user_id_id: user[:id]
end
```

So, what I want to be able to do is pass the @user variable to my set_document function in the render: partial => 'documents/resumelink' line in the first view and have it display a link to the resume (if there is one).

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to call controller method from view, right?

Comment: Yes, however, the view is not inside the documents class area, it is inside the user class area.  Guess I didn't make that clear judging by all the answers I got.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is more systemic than specific; and as such I'd like to give some ideas

---

**Controller**

When you use [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), it runs *before* your Rails action is run

This means when you send a request to Rails, it loads the `before_action` filter, and then the relevant action that you've *requested*. Partials do not form part of this process:

[image]

This means if you want to make various variables available to different parts of your application, you need to appreciate that it works as follows:

```
Request -> Router -> Controller#Action -> View -> Partial
```

To make use of the appropriate data, you need to ensure it's defined at the *correct*part of the above process. The problem you have is you're not doing that -- how can you make the `@user` variable available to a method *before* the `@user` variable has been defined?

This is not a specific issue for you now; but will be something you will need to keep in mind for next time.

---

**Partial**

If you're looking to include data in a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), you will need to use the [`locals`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) argument for the `render` method:

```
<%= render partial: "documents/resumelink", locals: { your_local_var: @value } %>
```

--

> So, what I want to be able to do is pass the @user variable to my set_document function in the render

As per my simple flow chart above, your partial will not invoke the `set_document` method, as a partial is literally just an *extension of your view*

You'll need to have the `@user` variable set in the **controller** (I set the [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark) for you) and then pass it as a local to your partial:

```
#app/models/request.rb
Class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, foreign_key: "student_id_id"
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :request, foreign_key: "student_id_id"
end

#app/controllers/documents_conroller.rb
Class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_document

   def index
       @requests = Request.all
   end

   private

   def set_document(user=@current_user)
       @document = Document.find_by owner_user_id_id: user[:id]
   end

end
```

This will allow you to call the following:

```
#app/views/requests/index.html.erb
<% @requests.each do |request| %>
   <% user = request.users.first %>
   <%= render partial: "documents/resumelink", locals: {user: user} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome response.  Thank you, I thought even partials called the documents controller first.  One thing I guess I didn't make clear though is that the first view is not under documents, its actually under users.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
<%= render :partial => 'documents/resumelink', :locals => {user => @user} %>
```

A variable `user` will be accessible in the partial.

Another way:
Variable `@user` is accessible without any changes in your code, because it is instance variable (not local)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I would do it differently.
Assigning variables (especially instance vars) in views is not a good practice, making DB queries from views is also quite bad.

What you can do instead is:

```
@requests = Request.where(your_conditions).includes(users: :documents)
```

and then i a view you can do

```
@requests.each do |request|
  request.user.email
  render partial: 'documents/resumelink', document: request.user.document
```

(actually you can do it already but solution proposed above will save you a lot of SQL queries)